In OMA Forms: How to create condition based on two input fields
I've created a form in Ontology Manager App with two timestamp input fields:
Started_at
End_at
Need to know how to create conditon or "override block" to check that
end_at must be more than 10 minutes greater than startet_at.
Expected resultat
If end_at is less than 10min. Display a message that says "condition is not valid" so that one can't be able to submitt the form by Action.
